# Height issues in react web app

Tags: reactjs

My theme size is not coming 100%.I am having a background which render inside the react app. But when i am running this code, my background is not coming 100% based on the screen size.

https://prnt.sc/jiijdo

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not include any code at all, it is very hard to help.

**But:** Because in React a component isn't allowed to have more than one child elements many "unused" divs are used. So my advice would be to get into the Developer Tool and search from the top (html > body > #root > etc) for a top level div that isn't the full height and style it to take the full viewport height (height: 100vh)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `min-height: 100vh` to the element of with your background, but it's like a **quick fix solution**. 
If you want to fix issue properly, please include a snippet of your code

Comment: yes its work. i just included this in my inline stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

const backgroundbg={
backgroundImage: 'url(' + Bgimg + ')', // ES6
            height:"100%",
            backgroundRepeat:"no-repeat",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
            minHeight: "100vh"
            }

this code works for me, it resolve my issues.